# SICStus Prolog weighted_maximum/3 replacement?

Tags: prolog, sat, clpb

SWI-Prolog CLP(B) has a weighted_maximum/2 predicate. What would be the replacement for this in SICStus Prolog CLP(B)? Here is an example what it does:

```
?- sat(A#B), weighted_maximum([1,2,1], [A,B,C], Maximum).
A = 0,
B = C, C = 1,
Maximum = 3.
```

I have no suggestion yet. Do I need to fall back to SICStus CLP(FD) for the pseudo boolean constraint inside the weighted_maximum/3? Would this even work?